# JSON_ERROR_UTF8(5) error while json_decode

Tags: laravel

I am trying to read a JSON file that contains an array of objects located in laravel storage and trying to iterate it. My attempt is as below.

```
$json = Storage::disk('local')->get('users.json');
json_decode($json, true);
```

This will return string type for the $json. So I cannot iterate. Anyone knows where I got wrong and how can I fix it?

Below is the part of my $json output.

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "url": "http://initech.tokoin.io.com/api/v2/users/1.json",
    "external_id": "74341f74-9c79-49d5-9611-87ef9b6eb75f",
    "name": "Francisca Rasmussen",
    "alias": "Miss Coffey",
    "created_at": "2016-04-15T05:19:46 -10:00",
    "active": true,
    "verified": true,
    "shared": false,
    "locale": "en-AU",
    "timezone": "Sri Lanka",
    "last_login_at": "2013-08-04T01:03:27 -10:00",
    "email": "coffeyrasmussen@flotonic.com",
    "phone": "8335-422-718",
    "signature": "Don't Worry Be Happy!",
    "organization_id": 119,
    "tags": [
      "Springville",
      "Sutton",
      "Hartsville/Hartley",
      "Diaperville"
    ],
    "suspended": true,
    "role": "admin"
  },
  {...}
]
```

Edit: `json_decode_error` function returns 5 which is unsupported utf8 characters included in the file is the issue.

Comment: store `json_decode` output in another variable and you can loop over that.

Comment: then it will return null for the new variable

Comment: can you include in question what do you have in your `$json` variable. Include output of `echo var_dump($json);die;` in the question itself.

Comment: that returns an array of objects which contains around 1940 lines in notepad output

Comment: you can include only a subset which can give us an idea. We might need recursive json_decode, just in case. One more thing, if it is already an array of object then why you're doing `json_decode`.

Comment: updated the question. $json type is also a string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223230/discussion-between-jitendra-yadav-and-m-cooper).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle `json_decode` error as follow using [`json_last_error`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php).

```
if ($json === null && json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
   echo "Incorrect json data.";
}
```

If you've unsupported `UTF-8` characters in your encoded json then convert them before decoding.

```
$input = Storage::disk('local')->get('users.json');
$json = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', utf8_encode($input));
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
```

If possible I suggest you to do the same while doing `json_encode`.

Comment: Thank You very much. It returns the array now.